# Uploading Application .apk to Google Play with different Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, facebook, google-play, apk

In the previous Eclipse that I used, my keyhash has been created and edited on developers.facebook. At the moment I am using a **different Eclipse** and have some doubts while creating new keystore and new apk.

My questions are

1-) Do I have to create new keyhash for my new Eclipse for developers.facebook?
(before it was required when I tried to login to application with facebook, but on my second eclipse I was not warned by the device)

2-) Will I lose my users on google play if my keystore **package and apk names are       different.**

Note: 
My **keystore** **password** is **same**. Thank you its so important for me.
android:versionCode has been increased

Comment: Use the same keystore.